# Ionic4 component - Menu: must have a 'content' element to listen for drag events on

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, stenciljs

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Ionic 4 - Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/dist/ionic.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', event => {
    document.querySelector('.button_details').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        document.querySelector('.menu_main').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <ion-menu class="menu_main" side="start">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
                <ion-title>Left Menu</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content padding>
            Hello World!
        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-menu-controller></ion-menu-controller>

    <ion-card style="display:inline-block;width:300px">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>Hello World</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <div style="padding:10px 10px;text-align:right;">
            <ion-button color="primary" class="button_details">Details</ion-button>
        </div>
    </ion-card>

</body>

</html>
```

**It works fine with one exception:** when the page loads, there is the following error on the console:

```
Error: "Menu: must have a 'content' element to listen for drag events on."
```

Here you have the `CodePen.io`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJgEzZ/?editors=1011

And below you can try the code right here on `StackOverflow`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', event => {
 document.querySelector('.button_details').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  document.querySelector('.menu_main').toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/dist/ionic.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <ion-menu class="menu_main" side="start">
  <ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>Left Menu</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
   Hello World!
  </ion-content>
 </ion-menu>
 <ion-menu-controller></ion-menu-controller>

 <ion-card style="display:inline-block;width:300px">
  <ion-card-header>
   <ion-card-title>Hello World</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <div style="padding:10px 10px;text-align:right;">
   <ion-button color="primary" class="button_details">Details</ion-button>
  </div>
 </ion-card>
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem? What is it missing here?

Could you please fork my `CodePen.io` with a proper code?

Thanks!

Comment: the error come from ion-menu-controller tag. if you don't want to use it, just  remove this tag.

Comment: even if you remove that tag, the error persists. you can try it by yourself.

Comment: ok replace ion-menu-controller and  add <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" main #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav> and test again.

Comment: could you please paste the `codepen.io` here? thanks!

Comment: ion-menu has the contentId property, try switching to
 `<ion-router-outlet id="content1" ..`
and
`<ion-menu contentId="content1"..`

Answer (score 43):

The`ion-menu` needs a `contentId` and the `ion-router-outlet` needs an `id`, so the menu `contentId` must be the `ion-router-outlet` id:

```
<ion-menu side="start" contentId="menuContent">
   <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-router-outlet id="menuContent"></ion-router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Many tutorials out there are outdated and don't reflect this.

Answer (score 22):

If you want the code:

Use `content-id="content"` and on ion-content `id="content"`, where the `id` is the identifier of the `ion-content` of the main view that is calling the menu.

```html
<ion-menu class="menu_main" side="start" content-id="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
            <ion-title>Left Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content padding>
        Hello World!
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu-controller></ion-menu-controller>
    
<ion-content id="content">
    <ion-card style="display:inline-block;width:300px">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>Hello World</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <div style="padding:10px 10px;text-align:right;">
            <ion-button color="primary" class="button_details">Details</ion-button>
        </div>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 10):

To those in the future you're probably running into the issue where you have a router outlet inside your ion-split-pane right?

Do this:

```
<ion-split-pane contentId="my-content">
     <ion-menu contentId="my-content"> ... </ion-menu>
     <ion-router-outlet id="my-content"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Note that the [main] attribute that was on your `ion-router-outlet` is now gone

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19618#issuecomment-540648915

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, error messages not clear how to handle this situation

Answer (score 4):

If you don't require the swipe gesture to open the menu you can add the `swipe-gesture="false"` attribute to the `ion-menu` tag. IMO this should get rid of the error but doesn't at the moment. I've created [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16127).
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzgRBj?editors=1011

If you want the swipe gesture to work you have to reference the content element's ID on the `ion-menu` element using the `content-id` attribute, see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqEpxE?editors=1011

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React and Ionic 6, the Ionic documentation is a bit outdated. I had to change the following items in order to menu appears:

1. Set `autoHide={false}` on IonMenuButton;
2. Set `menu="start"` on IonMenuButton (the value of menu property must be equal of IonMenu side property);

The code menu after adaptations:

```
  <IonMenu side="start" contentId="main-content">
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonTitle>Hello</IonTitle>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent>
      <IonList>
        <IonItem>Hello</IonItem>
      </IonList>
    </IonContent>
  </IonMenu>

  <div id="main-content">
    <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonButtons slot="start">
          <IonMenuButton autoHide={false} menu="start"></IonMenuButton>
        </IonButtons>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
  </div>
</IonApp>
```

The original code from ion-menu documentation -> https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/00c0885346e0f048bb2c2bda104ea26cd9d1ff52/static/demos/api/menu/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To Whom it may concern, this is what I did:

```
<ion-split-pane contentId="main">
    <ion-menu side="start" contentId="main">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>LogOut</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Adding contentId="main" works for me Thank you

Comment: Without a description of what part of the example code you provided solves the problem, it is difficult to understand why it solves it. Even if the code is good, without explanation it's not a solution yet.