# Angular Ionic Side Drawer does not render

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an angular ionic app and I am trying to set up a side drawer.  I have the following in very basic code which is based off of the ionic starter app.  I can't figure out why my side drawer does not render.  I've followed samples and looked at the ionic documentation.

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu side="start">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Sample App
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="business" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Sample Drawer Item</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

test.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menuitem menu="m1"></ion-menuitem>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>places</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer found here: [Ionic4 component - Menu: must have a 'content' element to listen for drag events on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003274/ionic4-component-menu-must-have-a-content-element-to-listen-for-drag-events).

The official documentation does mention `content-id="main"` in the ion-menu property, but does not mention adding it to `<ion-content id="content">`.  Without adding `id="content"` to `ion-content` as suggested in the linked post above, it didn't work for me.